# Search a dataframe and output matched values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CSV's (News.csv and Country.csv), I am trying to search for country names in one of the News.csv through a list of country names available in Country.csv.

I am able to find whether there is a match or not and display a boolean value.

News CSV

[image: News head]

Country CSV

[image: Country head]

```
news.dropna(inplace = True)
news.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace = True)
country_list = country['Country'].values
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", 'This pattern has match groups')
news['Test'] = news['Title'].str.contains('|'.join(country_list), case = 
False, regex = True)
```

After performing the search on the Title column

[image: Search]

However I would like to display the matched country instead. Moreover, is there a way to query more than 1 column at a time? For instance searching through both Title and Url at once.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need join columns together:

```
pat = '|'.join(country_list)
s = news['url'].add(news['Title'])
```

For first match use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
news['Test'] = s.str.extract('('+ pat + ')', flags=re.I, expand=False)
```

For all match use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for lists and if need strings with separator add [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
news['Test'] = s.str.extract(pat, flags=re.I).str.join(', ')
```